# DataAccessLayer and organize solution

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern

I have a MVC solution :

[image]

In my different file :

Library.DataAccessLayer.LibraryContext.cs :

```
namespace Library.DataAccessLayer
{
    public class LibraryContext : DbContext
    {
        public LibraryContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Library.DataAccessLayer.Models.Author.cs :

```
namespace Library.DataAccessLayer.Models
{
    public class Author
    {
        [Key]
        public int AuthorID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        .........

    }

}
```

Library.DataAccessLayer.Repositories.AuthorRepository.cs :

```
namespace Library.DataAccessLayer.Repositories
{
    public class AuthorRepository : IDisposable, IAuthorRepository
    {
        private LibraryContext context;

        public AuthorRepository(LibraryContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Author> GetAuthors()
        {
            return context.Authors.ToList();
        }

        public Author GetAuthorById(int id)
        {
            return .........
        }

        ............
    }
}
```

And in Library.Controllers.AuthorController :

```
namespace Library.Controllers
{
    public class AuthorController : Controller
    {
        private IAuthorRepository authorRepository;

        public AuthorController()
        {
            this.authorRepository = new AuthorRepository(new LibraryContext());
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var authors = authorRepository.GetAuthors();

            return View(authors);
        }
    }
 }
```

1/ This architecture is coherent ?

2/ Is it really useful to declare interfaces for my repositories which are implemented in my repository classes ?

3/ In my AuthorRepository, the declaration and call of the LibraryContext is correct?

4/ In my AuthorController, my declaration and call of AuthorRepository is correct ?

5/ In which folder can we put the file LibraryContext ? (If necessary and useful)

6/ Is it good to group repositories  interfaces and repositories class in the same folder? If not, how to separate and name the various folders ?

7/ How to improve that?

I need your advices.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. I find the architecture simple, which is good, maybe as your application grows you'll need more layers
2. Yeah, is really good, specially if you are going to use dependency injection, which leads to the next questions.
3. Your implementation is right, as for dependencies you should use some design patterns as, again, dependency injection or factory. All your dependencies should be instantiated outside.
4. This one should be the same as the previous one, the repository should be instantiated outside.
5. The structure is supposed to accommodate your needs, but I find the example in [here](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2016/03/07/how-to-implement-the-repository-pattern-in-asp-net-mvc-application.aspx) pretty useful
6. Many developers do it that way, some also, and some others, like me, keep them in separate files, personally I create a 'contracts' folder alongside my repositories and keep the interfaces there.
7. The best way to find a convention that accommodates you is reading code from other developers, there you will find many styles, structures, architecture and pattern implementations.

I hope you find this useful, **May the force be with you**

Comment: If I want to create a `RepositoryFactory` or `DbContextFactory`, where to put my different files? In dal project ? How to name the directories that host files ? Thanks!

Comment: And is it correct to create a repository for each table (entity/model) ? Even if there is only one method in repository ?

Comment: I think it would be better if you create a generic repository, using `Context.Set<T>()` you can implement it, and you could set the Factories in the same namespace than the classes.

Answer (score 0):

This question is more fit to [Codereview website](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but I think it deserves an answer here:

1. **Repositories** are fine, but you should also consider defining a service layer. Services are responsible for aggregating information using repositories and providing this information using service models. Sending back data models (e.g. `Author`s) might lead to trouble because:

   - serialization can fail if navigation properties create cycles
   - you want to provide more information that is not related to data layer (e.g. some computed stuff)

Example:

```
class AuthorServiceModel
{
    int AuthorId { get; set; }
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    // ...
}

class LibraryService : ILibraryService      // if DI is used
{
    public AuthorServiceModel GetAuthorById(int id)
    {
        // error handling/logging may be put here, if an invalid id is provided

        var author = context.Authors.Get(id);
        // auto mapping can be used to avoid the typing - check http://automapper.org/
        var sm = new AuthorServiceModel { AuthorId = author.AuthorId, FirstName = author.FirstName };
        return sm;
    }

    // 
}

The controller will never have to know about your data access layer
```

2) **Repositories unification** - if most of your repositories are doing just the standard operations (get all, get by identifier, update entity, remove entity etc.), you may define a generic typed repository that helps you to avoid the repetition:

```
class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    private LibraryContext context;

    public IQueryable<T> All => context.Set<T>().AsQueryable();

    public IQueryable<T> AllNoTracking => context.Set<T>().AsNoTracking();

    public T Get(int id)
    {
        return context.Set<T>().Find(id);
    }

    // other methods
}
```

3) Implementing interfaces can be useful when using Dependency Injection - DI (e.g. [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/)). This removes some coupling between your classes and also allows automatic testing (bindings can be changed to mock objects). E.g.:

```
public class LibraryContext : DbContext, ILibraryContext
{
    public LibraryContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    // other methods here
}

public class AuthorRepository : IDisposable, IAuthorRepository
{
    private ILibraryContext context;

    // the context will be injected and should not be provided by the caller, if DI is used
    public AuthorRepository(ILibraryContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    // other methods come here
}

public class AuthorController : Controller
{
    // this allows for automatic injection based on defined bindings
    [Inject]
    public IAuthorRepository authorRepository { get; set; }

    public AuthorController()
    {
        // no need for this, as DI takes care of the initialization
        // also, controller does not have to know about your data access classes
        // this.authorRepository = new AuthorRepository(new LibraryContext());
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var authors = authorRepository.GetAuthors();
        return View(authors);
    }
}
```

4) Grouping of files is a matter of taste, but I usually recommend groping them semantically (all classes and interfaces that do similar jobs in a folder). Also, data context and repositories are quite coupled and they can reside in the same project/assembly.

Also, services can be separated in their own project/assembly.

**NOTE:** For a more thorough analysis, consider providing all the code related to your patterns and post your question on Codereview (they deal with complete and working code, not just fragments). It is a great chance that someone will cover all the topics from naming to the patterns).

Comment: The question doesn't contain working code and is off-topic for CR.